# GStreamer plugins 'interpipe' (Ridgerun) and intervideo do not handle RGB format

Tags: gstreamer

I am trying to use RidgeRun's [Interpipe](https://github.com/RidgeRun/gst-interpipe) plugin. When the input video is I420, it works fine, but negotiation fails with RGB video.

Below the gst-launch commands I use in my app.

```
"videotestsrc ! video/x-raw,format=xRGB ! interpipesink name=camera sync=false"
"interpipesrc name=display listen-to=camera accept-events=false accept-eos-event=false enable-sync=false allow-renegotiation=false ! autovideosink sync=false async=false"
```

And the error I get:

```
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline1/GstInterPipeSrc:display: Internal data stream error.
Additional debug info:
gstbasesrc.c(3055): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline1/GstInterPipeSrc:display:
streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)

WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3055:gst_base_src_loop:<display1> error: Internal data stream error.

WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3055:gst_base_src_loop:<display1> error: streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)
```

Is RGB not supported? How do I find out what formats are supported?

I get the same error from the **intervideosrc/sink** plugin, and was hoping the interpipe plugin would not have this limitation.

If this is so, what other solution do I have?

Can someone provide pointers as to how to add support for additional formats (I've started looking at the source code for interpipe, but any pointer would be appreciated).